# How can I share a Leiningen template?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I have created a Leiningen template for a Clojure webapp. How can I share this to other users of Leiningen?

### Update

I am still trying to figure out how to do this. I created a template here:

https://clojars.org/repo/webdb/

: but it will not install, so I have created another question:

[How can I deploy a Leiningen template to Clojars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171739/how-can-i-deploy-a-leiningen-template-to-clojars)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- make a project on github with your template.
- publish the jar on clojars. `lein deploy clojars`
- pop into the #liningen IRC channel on freenode if you want someone to test it out for you
- publish! (put a link to the project in this question would be a start) and send it to the leiningen mailing list.

Comment: Can i do this without publishing on github?

Comment: sure, github is not at all required just common.