# How can I deploy a Leiningen template to Clojars?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript, clojars

I have created a Leiningen project on my local machine which I then turn into a template by doing:

```
lein create-template webdb
```

: Then I install the template:

```
cd webdb
lein install
```

: which allows me to create projects based on the template locally:

```
lein new webdb anewproject
```

: Everything works fine up to here. However if I try to deploy the template to clojars using:

```
cd webdb
lein deploy clojars
```

: then whenever I try to use the clojars profile to create a template I get an error:

```
lein new org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb anothernewproject
```

: gives the error:

```
Could not find metadata org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/faroukzquraishi/.m2/repository)
Failure to find org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Failure to find org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in http://clojars.org/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of clojars has elapsed or updates are forced
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
Could not find template org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb on the classpath.
```

: does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

### Update - project.clj

```
(defproject cljstemplate "org.clojars.zubairq2/webdb"
  :dependencies [
                   [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                   [org.clojure/google-closure-library-third-party "0.0-2029"]
                   [domina "1.0.1"]
                   [crate "0.2.4"]
                   [prismatic/dommy "0.1.1"]
                   [korma "0.3.0-RC5"]
                   [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.2-1002-jdbc4"]
                   [compojure "1.1.5"]
                   [shoreleave "0.3.0"]
                   [shoreleave/shoreleave-remote-ring "0.3.0"]
                   [ring-middleware-format "0.3.0"]
                   [ring/ring-json "0.2.0"]
                   [jayq "2.3.0"]
                ]

  :url "http://org.clojars.zubair2/webdb"

  :plugins  [
               [lein-cljsbuild "0.3.0"]
               [lein-httpd "1.0.0"]
               [lein-ring "0.8.5"]
            ]

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :ring {:handler webapp.framework.server.core/app}

  :cljsbuild
  {
    :builds
     [
      {
         :source-paths ["src"]
         :compiler     {
                         :output-to      "resources/public/main.js"
                         :optimizations  :simple
                         :externs        ["resources/public/jquery.js" "resources/public/google_maps_api_v3_3.js"]
                         :pretty-print   false
                       }
      }
     ]

  }
)
```

Comment: Could you include the project.clj for the template? If that does not use the fully qualified name then it could cause this problem

Answer (score 3):

your upload seems to have worked and the result is here:

https://clojars.org/webdb/lein-template

you can make a project like this:

```
arthur@a:~$ lein new webdb newproject
Retrieving webdb/lein-template/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/lein-template-0.1.0-20130618.143034-5.pom from clojars
Retrieving webdb/lein-template/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/lein-template-0.1.0-20130618.143034-5.jar from clojars
```

Comment: I just ran "lein new webdb newproject" but it didn't retreive any dependencies. It just made a new leiningen black default project (I installed leiningen fresh on a new machine and then tried it)

Comment: When I run it get the project.clj you posted above, the name in the project.clj is wrong (it should use the value supplied to the template) though the template is working.  you may have to use lien -U new webdb name to cause it to fetch snapshot dependencies, or give your template a non snapshot version number.

Comment: What is a non snapshot version number?

Comment: When I run  "lein -U new webdb newproject" it says, "That is not a task". Which version of Leiningen should I be using?

Comment: I tried both Lein 1,7 and Lein 2.2, but it does not work with either of this. There must be some special setup involved for lein?

Comment: I added {:user {:plugins [[lein-clojars "0.9.1"]]}} to .lein/profiles.clj but this still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

To use a lein plugin, you must make it a dependency it in your .lein/profiles.clj

Since you project is on clojars, if you add its dependency it should be available to you.

Comment: Do I need to add the line {:user {:plugins [[lein-clojars "0.9.1"]]}} to .lein/profiles.clj?

Comment: I added this, it retreives the dependencies now, but it still says it fails to find the webdb Maven Metadata